# Mass acknowledgement of alerts in icinga

Tags: monitoring, icinga2

How to acknowledge similar alerts for a server at one single go in icinga.
 Please suggest.

Thanks
Ritu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Icingaweb2 interface, you can mass-select alerts using the [Shift]-key. You can then acknowledge all selected alerts with the same acknowledgement.

[image: acknowledge multiple alerts]